# How is the presence of water detected on celestial bodies?

Tags: water, europa, detection

How is the presence of water detected on celestial bodies and how is its state, solid or liquid, determined? In a related question, are the same methods used to detect the presence of subsurface water, e.g [the subsurface ocean on Europa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa_(moon)#Subsurface_ocean)?

Comment: Also see [How many moons in the solar system have water?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28562/7982)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterrestrial_liquid_water you find your answer here.

Comment: Folks lets leave this question open so that users will have an opportunity to write an answer this weekend. In this case there's no need for pre-blocking of answers here. **The occasional canonical question leading to a canonical answer is one of those special success stories in SE that everyone can benefit from.**

Comment: I think our excellent answer-writers can cover it well, especially if they link to longer answers here and in Astronomy SE for background details. These are different questions but have some potentially helpful answers: [What's the scientific evidence of water for return trip methalox on Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23763/12102) and [What forms of water ice have been observed and verified in the solar system?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18374/12102).